# Swift - Add UIImageView as subview of UIWebView scrollView and scaling

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` and I have successfully added a `UIImage` view to the `UIWebView`’s `scrollView` like so:

```
let localUrl = String(format:"%@/%@", PDFFilePath, fileNameGroup)
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(localUrl)

        panRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panDetected))
        pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pinchDetected))

        panRecognizer.delegate = self
        pinchRecognizer.delegate = self

        webview = UIWebView()
        webview.frame = self.view.bounds
        webview.scrollView.frame = webview.frame

        webview.userInteractionEnabled = true
        webview.scalesPageToFit = true
        webview.becomeFirstResponder()
        webview.delegate = self
        webview.scrollView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(webview)
        webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL:url))
        webview.gestureRecognizers = [pinchRecognizer, panRecognizer]

let stampView:StampAnnotation = StampAnnotation(imageIcon: UIImage(named: "approved.png"), location: CGPointMake(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y))
            self.webview.scrollView.addSubview(stampView)
```

My `UIWebView` `scrollView` is scalable. Now I am looking for away to have my `UIImageView` (`StampAnnotation` is a class and `UIImageView` is its subclass) scale when the `scrollView` scales. So if the user zooms in on the `scrollView`, the `UIImageView` will get bigger and stay in a fixed position and if the user zooms out, the `UIImageView` will get smaller while the `scrollView` gets smaller while staying in a fixed position.

I really hope that makes sense. I have tried the following:

```
func pinchDetected(recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
    {

        for views in webview.scrollView.subviews
        {
            if(views.isKindOfClass(UIImageView))
            {
                views.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(views.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
                recognizer.scale = 1
            }
        }

        if(appDelegate.annotationSelected == 0)
        {
            webview.scalesPageToFit = true
        }
        else
        {
            webview.scalesPageToFit = false
        }

    }
```

but this does nothing, if I remove this line:

```
recognizer.scale = 1
```

it scales way too big too fast. My question is, how do I get my `UIImageView` to scale when the `UIWebview`’s `scrollView` scrolls?

Any help would be appreciated.

This solved my problem.

```
func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    for views in webview.scrollView.subviews
    {
        if(views.isKindOfClass(UIImageView))
        {
            views.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scrollView.zoomScale, scrollView.zoomScale)
        }
    }

}
```

No it does not stay in a fixed position on the page, but I think that is a constraints issue?

Comment: why don't you add the image by editing the HTML displayed by the page?

Comment: you mean, add the image via HTML in the page that is loaded? if so, that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: why not, what will it not do that you require?

Comment: its not what I am looking for because I am adding the UIImageView on device touch

Comment: Could run JavaScript from the same trigger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close...

1) Add a **property** to hold onto an external reference for your stampViewFrame:

```
var stampViewFrame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
```

2) Replace your scrollViewDidZoom() with this:

```
 func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for views in webView.scrollView.subviews
    {
        if(views.isKindOfClass(UIImageView))
        {
            views.frame = CGRect(x: stampViewFrame.origin.x * scrollView.zoomScale, y: stampViewFrame.origin.y * scrollView.zoomScale, width: stampViewFrame.width * scrollView.zoomScale, height: stampViewFrame.height * scrollView.zoomScale)
        }
    }
}
```

3) Finally, because the zoom scale resets to 1 at the begining of each new zooming action, you need to adjust the value of your stampViewFrame property:

```
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(scrollView: UIScrollView, withView view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    stampViewFrame = CGRect(x: stampViewFrame.origin.x * scale, y: stampViewFrame.origin.y * scale, width: stampViewFrame.width * scale, height: stampViewFrame.height * scale)
}
```

I also tried to answer your other question about layout during orientation change, but I now have a much better understanding of what you are trying to do.  If you want your stampView to always be on in the same place relative to the **web content**, you have to get into HTML/JS because the webpage lays itself out dynamically.  A much much more simple (and hopefully close enough) solution would be to add the following:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    webView.frame = view.bounds
    stampView.frame = stampViewFrame
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much....just one thing, my image is 150 in width and 73 in height and when I start scaling or rotate my image looks a little squished. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: There was a typo in scrollViewDidZoom().  I've fixed it in the response.

Comment: There is an issue in your code, when I goto scale in and then stop and then goto scale again, the image is much larger and in the wrong position.

Comment: @user979331 I've tested it and didn't have that problem.  Sounds like you are having an issue with the scrollViewDidEndZooming() part.  Sorry I can't debug your project.

Answer (score 1):

Use the scroll delegate method of `scrollViewDidZoom` :

```
     func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView){
         //Change the subview of scroll frame as per the scroll frame scale
         //rect = initial position & size of the image.<class instance> 
         stampView.frame = CGRectMake((CGRectGetMaxX(rect)-rect.size.width)*webView.scrollView.zoomScale, (CGRectGetMaxY(rect)-rect.size.height)*webView.scrollView.zoomScale, rect.width*webView.scrollView.zoomScale,rect.height*webView.scrollView.zoomScale)
     }
```

Comment: I get an error with this code: `Use of unresolved identifier 'rect'`

Comment: What is rect KumarKL ?

Comment: initial position & size of the image.